# xsl - how to retrieve the value of a xml node based on another value of a xml node

Tags: xslt

assuming that I have following xml:

```
    <ns5:OrderTotal>
    <ns5:Name>AmountPaid</ns5:Name>
        <ns5:Description>Payment Received</ns5:Description>
    <ns5:SortOrder>4</ns5:SortOrder>
    <ns5:Value>16.95</ns5:Value>
    </ns5:OrderTotal>
    <ns5:OrderTotal>
    <ns5:Name>AmountDue</ns5:Name>
        <ns5:Description>Current Amount Due</ns5:Description>
    <ns5:SortOrder>5</ns5:SortOrder>
    <ns5:Value>0.0</ns5:Value>
    </ns5:OrderTotal>
```

If I only want print the Value of the OrderTotal when it Name is AmountPaid, how could achieve this?

Thank you for the helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you are going to print the value you need, but it can be gathered using the following XPath expression:

```
//ns5:OrderTotal[child::ns5:Name = 'AmountPaid']/ns5:Value
```

For example:

XML:

```
<ns5:Orders xmlns:ns5="a">
    <ns5:OrderTotal>
        <ns5:Name>AmountPaid</ns5:Name>
        <ns5:Description>Payment Received</ns5:Description>
        <ns5:SortOrder>4</ns5:SortOrder>
        <ns5:Value>16.95</ns5:Value>
    </ns5:OrderTotal>
    <ns5:OrderTotal>
        <ns5:Name>AmountDue</ns5:Name>
        <ns5:Description>Current Amount Due</ns5:Description>
        <ns5:SortOrder>5</ns5:SortOrder>
        <ns5:Value>0.0</ns5:Value>
    </ns5:OrderTotal>
</ns5:Orders>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl" version="1.0"
    xmlns:ns5="a">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="Value">
        <xsl:value-of select="//ns5:OrderTotal[child::ns5:Name = 'AmountPaid']/ns5:Value"/>
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Value>16.95</Value>
```

Comment: @yupinghe, you are welcome. If you think that this is the correct answer to your question, please mark it as so.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:if test="Name = 'AmountPaid'">
 <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Try the above `XSL`.

Comment: thx, but i tried this and it seems to return the Value of the first node regardlessly. So if there is another node called "ShippingPaid" before AmountPaid, it will return ShippingPaid value.